# How can I make a Flatlist not scrollable in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, scrollable

I would like to know can I make a flatlist not scrollable for a moment. For example: there is a boolean constant that  whenever is true, you can scroll the flatlist but whenever is false, how can I make it so that it can not be scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FlatList inherits props of ScrollView according to [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), so it should have `scrollEnabled` prop ScrollView [props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#props)
and try setting it up as:

```
scrollEnabled={ false }
```

in your FlatList props.